# Stripe Connect: In Stripe Connect who will pay the Stripe Charge, how to make sure that?

Tags: stripe-payments, strip-tags

We are developing an application for restaurant usage, in that we have integrated Stripe Payment Gateway. Our application is having 3 types of users, Admin, Restaurant and Customer. Admin will take a charge from Merchant for using the application in each order they place through the application.

To manage this Payment Transaction we have used Stripe Connect, for example, if Customer is paying $2 then admin will take $0.5 as an application fee, and the merchant will receive the $1.5, but here the question is who will pay the Stripe Charge. We need that, Merchant will bear the Stripe Charge.

Here is the screenshot of a successful transaction. Can anyone guide me about this make sure?

[image: Screenshot of Transaction]

Answer (score 0):

You should review the [different types of charge flows](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges#choosing-approach) available when using Connect. Based on what you've described, it sounds like you want [Direct charges](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges), with the fees paid by the connected account, but it really depends on the details of your business. You can review the [fund flow diagram](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges#flow-of-funds-with-fees) to see if it matches what you need.